# How To Fix UITextView in storyboard TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, cgrectmake

Here i want to fix a UITextView which i created programatically in textView added on storyboard. I have tried it this way but not working.

_textView is a textView in which i have to fix UITextView *descrip

contentView is the view on which i have _textView.

```
  UITextView *descrip = [[UITextView alloc]init];

  descrip.view.frame = CGRectMake(_textView.frame.origin.x,_textView.frame.origin.y,_textView.frame.size.width,_textView.frame.size.height);

  [self.contentView addSubview:descrip.view];
```

Comment: u have to fix _dsecrip inside _textView right...

Comment: yes you are right @Uday.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is proper method

```
UITextView *descrip = [[UITextView alloc]initWithframe:CGRectMake(_textView.frame.origin.x,_textView.frame.origin.y,_textView.frame.size.width,_textView.frame.size.height)]
  [self.contentView addSubview:descrip];
```

Comment: no this doesn't work i had tried this before @PinkeshGjr

Comment: there must be some other issue if you cant do this using this code. cross check your code

Comment: it is giving me warnings that local declaration hides instance variable, actually it works with iPhone 5s simulator in portrait mode. But in landscape mode it shows up in half of the width portion only. with iPhone 6 it loses it's position @PinkeshGjr

Comment: this warning comes when you declare global variable again whit same name as local variable . change local variable name and try again

Comment: at 2nd line in your code section it is giving me error, Local declaration of discrip hides instance variable @PinkeshGjr

Comment: and what about that it loses position in landscape mode for different devices  @PinkeshGjr

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this--

```
UITextView *descrip = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:_textView.frame];
[self.contentView addSubview:descrip];
```

there is no need to to use `CGRectMake` if you want to give same frame as `_textView` `frame`.

Comment: in landscape mode it shows in half portion only widthwise hight is fine and on other device i don't know what happens it loses the position. An my scrollview is also not working in 6 and 6 plus simulator it is working on 5s simulator @Dev.RK

Comment: have you added any constraints to _textView in storyboard

Comment: yes i have added all constrains including height and width @Dev.RK

Comment: get those constrains of _textView and add this constraints to descrip textview. Hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: means i dint get you buddy, and what about my scroll why it's working on only 5s and not on 6 and 6plus @Dev.RK

Comment: I'm saying that you have added width/height contraints to _textView in storyboard. So that when you rotate your device _textView adjust height and width according landscape mode. But in descrip textview you only set frame of _textView thats why when you rotate device its height/ width remains same.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But now we have used  initWithFrame:_textView.frame];  so how to set width and height for it @Dev.RK

Comment: So get _textView constraints programmatically and add this to desrip textview

Comment: _textView is on storyboard so how would i get them programatically @Dev.RK

Comment: add this line [descrip addConstraints:_textView.constraints]; before adding descrip textview to your contentview

Comment: by adding that line it makes a crash, giving error  reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'
@Dev.RK

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: how to do that@Dev.RK

Comment: take screenshot of your storyboard and add to your question.

Comment: add this autoResizingMask-- descrip.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

Comment: and remove the line which crashing app.

Comment: it's only working on iPhone 5s simulator but not on 6 and 6 plus and on 5s also it leaves little space at both the ends

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to add descrip into_textView; try this:

```
UITextView *descrip =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _textView.frame.size.width, _textView.frame.size.height)];
descrip.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:descrip];  //here add subview to texview not content view
```

Comment: thanks but, this is wrong actually setting x,y 0,0 will move it to corner of view and Using this  self.textView addSubview:descrip will hide behind the content view @Uday.M

Comment: @vicky : on contentView you are having textView right

Comment: yes it is like view-scrollView-contentView then textView on it.

Comment: then why it will hide behind content view

Comment: but its not showing it if i do it the way you suggested @Uday.M

Comment: check "debug View heirarchy", and see whether it is hiding behind content view

Comment: @vicky : i given x,y to 0,0 bcoz u want same width as _textView, if not given that some of text view will be hidden or it will move out of frame